# How to disable FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT when using Doctrine generate migration?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I often change/add some field in Entity and using `bin/console make:migration` to generate migrations, that's convenience just like in Rails or Django. But I do not need Foreign Key Constraint when I am using Doctrine Relationships(`ManyToOne`, `OneToMany`...).

I have to delete lines contained Foreign Key Constraint in generated migrations. But When I doing some changes with Entity, and run `bin/console make:migration`, It will add Foreign Key Constraint again, it is annoying.

I do not care about data consistency.

In Django model ForeignKey you can set `db_constraint=False`, so migration would not generate Foreign Key constraint.

Is there some similar setting in Doctrine?

Comment: I'm sorry but there is really no built-in method in Doctrine to do this, as I say in my answer. If you really want no FKs and want to use doctrine to generate the schema automatically; you'll have to delete the statements manually.

Comment: but it will auto generate `Foreign Key Constraint` again and again when I create/change some entities migrations

Comment: Yes, it will. If you use Doctrine to generate modify the schema, these FK constraints will be generated. Again, Doctrine does not support association mapping without using FKs on relational backends, as I said in my answer.

Comment: you can do that with some code in a listener attached to `postGenerateSchema` event. See my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doctrine does not support this.

If you are using a relational back-end and declare association mappings between your entities, the generated code **will include the appropriate foreign keys**.

You are not *required* to use that code. If the FKs does not exist Doctrine will continue working fine, as you've discovered.

> I do not care about data consistency

Oh, to be young and care-fee. Good luck with that.

Comment: There are cases that FK cause performance issue due to unnecessary locking by the current design.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852942/mysql-insert-blocked-by-an-update-of-the-foreign-key-referenced-row
I am also looking for a systematic way to disable this. Thanks for the answers that everyone contributes.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you just do the following?

```
$this->addSql('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
// all SQL statements
$this->addSql('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
```

This works.

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine doesn't support this natively, but you can do that with an event listener on `postGenerateSchema` event.

```
// src/Doctrine/IgnoreFksListener.php

namespace App\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Event\GenerateSchemaEventArgs;

/**
 * see http://kamiladryjanek.com/en/ignore-entity-or-table-when-running-doctrine2-schema-update-command/
 */
class IgnoreFksListener
{

    /**
     * Remove fks from Schema
     * This listener is called when the schema has been generated (from mapping data of entities)
     *
     * @param GenerateSchemaEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postGenerateSchema(GenerateSchemaEventArgs $args)
    {
        $schema = $args->getSchema();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();

        foreach ($schema->getTables() as $table) {
            $fks = $table->getForeignKeys();
            foreach ($fks as $fk) {
                $table->removeForeignKey($fk->getName());
//              dump('removed FK '.$fk->getName().' from '.$tabel->getName().' pointing to '.$fk->getForeignTableName().'.['.implode(', ', $fk->getForeignColumns()).']');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you have to register the listener in `services.yaml`

```
    App\Doctrine\IgnoreFksListener:
        tags:
            - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postGenerateSchema }
```

here you can find another example 
http://kamiladryjanek.com/en/ignore-entity-or-table-when-running-doctrine2-schema-update-command/